# Backup Working, What Else to Backup?

Tags: ubuntu, backup, web-server

I am running a Ubuntu web server. I have a backup script working that will dump mysql and svn and backup both of those along with the files in the /var/www folder and store it on S3. What else should be backed up?

Currently, I am running the following:

- Apache
- MySql
- Subversion

Eventually I may play with other things.

Comment: What services are you running? SVN, WWW, what else?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to determine what you need to back-up is to walk through a scenario where your server's hard drive is no longer booting up.

What data would you require to bring it online as fast as possible?

This is a basic template (tailored to *BSD) that I use:

Files:

```
/etc/ssh
/var/log
/var/cron
/etc/ipfw.rules (ip tables in your case)
/etc/syslog.conf 
/etc/motd
/etc/ssh/banner
/etc/shells
/etc/profile
/etc/login.conf
/etc/group
/etc/hosts
/etc/passwd
/etc/sysctl.conf
/etc/resolv.conf
/etc/rc.conf
/etc/rc.local
/etc/crontab
/etc/master.passw
```

Dirs:

```
/var/cron
```

If you are running other services; you should back-up those configurations as well.

Comment: Should I just backup /etc?

Comment: You can, but in most cases it's an over kill. You can just back-up / then :)

Answer (score 2):

For each service, you need to backup:

- Apache:

  - /var/www/html (and any other place where you store this kind of files)
  - /etc/httpd (I think it's /etc/apache2 in Debian's like)
- MySQL:

  - mysqldump and binary logs if present
  - /etc/my.cnf
  - Optional you may backup /var/lib/mysql
- Subversion:

  - Repository directory
  - Permission files